# Do Snowflake transient tables survive a database restart?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm curious if transient tables for Snowflake will survive a database restart? If not, how would you use Time Travel to recover that data since these table types are not part of a backup log record, etc.

I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by a database restart?

Comment: HI , check this link for time travel for Transient table in Snowflake, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is a lot to unpack from your question.  Databases in Snowflake don't "restart" for starters.  Databases are simply a storage of data.  "Backup log" doesn't exist, either.  Time Travel tracks every change in a table, including transient tables.  Transient tables have a limit of 1 day of time-travel, though, which I believe is the crux of your question.  The link that @HimanshuKandpal provided should answer your questions on the difference in table types in Snowflake.